# Converting [NSDate date] to a localized UTC date string

Tags: ios, objective-c, timezone, nsdate

I have an `NSDate` object that I am sending to an API that we use. Our app is used across the world, so the API is wanting the date to be in UTC, e.g.:

```
"/Date(1481704200000)/"
```

However, the date needs to have the timezone offset taken into account since the API/server is not doing this for us. If we don't do this, the date is incorrect when we view it on the server.

I am doing the following, which seems to produce an incorrect date:

```
// Offset
float timezoneoffset = [[NSTimeZone localTimeZone] secondsFromGMT];

// Date
CFTimeInterval startDate = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
startDate = startDate - timezoneoffset;
NSString *dateStarted = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Date(%.0f000)/", startDate];
```

How can I correctly take the local time zone into account and create a correctly formatted UTC date string?

Comment: timeIntervalSince1970 is counted on UTC.  So you don't need to convert.  https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdate/1407504-timeintervalsince1970

Comment: I think you are making a mistake on the 2nd line.  What do you get for NSLog with timezoneoffset?  Actually, sorry, my mistake...

Answer (score 5):

There is no need for any timezone manipulation.

```
NSTimeInterval interval = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
NSString *dateStarted = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Date(%.0f)/", interval * 1000];
```

This gives you the time in UTC regardless of the user's timezone.

Try it. Run this code with several different timezone settings on your test device and you will get the same result in every case.

Comment: You are missing the point. I understand how to create a string with the UTC date. But, as stated, because of the way the API processes dates, I DO need to change the UTC time in seconds and recalculate this based on the timezone offset. Either adding or subtracting seconds. This was my question.

Comment: @NicHubbard That makes no sense. All the server has to do is know that all string values are in UTC and there's nothing special to do.

Comment: It does make sense when the API has a bug that makes this required.

Comment: You need to clarify the issue. How can there be such a bug? If the server expects a string in UTC time, then how can it matter what the user's timezone is if all users send a string in UTC time? How would adjusting the sent string to account for the user's timezone make any difference if the server doesn't know what timezone the user is in and simply expects a UTC based string? Why make all clients of the server jump through hoops instead of the server being fixed?

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
```

Now it is in UTC, (at least after using the method below)
To store this time as UTC (since refernce date 1970) use

```
double secsUtc1970 = [[NSDate date]timeIntervalSince1970];
```

Set Date formatter to output local time:

```
NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
// or Timezone with specific name like
// [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Europe/Riga"] 
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:timeZone];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"];
NSString *localDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currentDate];
```

`NSDate` object always uses UTC as time reference, but the string representation of a date is not neccessarily based on UTC timezone.

To get timezones, you can use this:

```
NSTimeZone* timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
NSString* timeZoneName = [timeZone localizedName:NSTimeZoneNameStyleStandard locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
NSLog(@"Name : %@", timeZoneName);
```

If you call `[NSTimeZone abbreviationDictionary]` you'll get a dictionary containing all available abbreviations.

```
NSLog(@"%@",[NSTimeZone abbreviationDictionary]);
```

Result :

```
2015-07-10 11:44:05.954 APP[1472:26120] {
    ADT = "America/Halifax";
    AKDT = "America/Juneau";
    AKST = "America/Juneau";
    ART = "America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires";
    AST = "America/Halifax";
    BDT = "Asia/Dhaka";
    BRST = "America/Sao_Paulo";
    BRT = "America/Sao_Paulo";
    BST = "Europe/London";
    CAT = "Africa/Harare";
    CDT = "America/Chicago";
    CEST = "Europe/Paris";
    CET = "Europe/Paris";
    CLST = "America/Santiago";
    CLT = "America/Santiago";
    COT = "America/Bogota";
    CST = "America/Chicago";
    EAT = "Africa/Addis_Ababa";
    EDT = "America/New_York";
    EEST = "Europe/Istanbul";
    EET = "Europe/Istanbul";
    EST = "America/New_York";
    GMT = GMT;
    GST = "Asia/Dubai";
    HKT = "Asia/Hong_Kong";
    HST = "Pacific/Honolulu";
    ICT = "Asia/Bangkok";
    IRST = "Asia/Tehran";
    IST = "Asia/Calcutta";
    JST = "Asia/Tokyo";
    KST = "Asia/Seoul";
    MDT = "America/Denver";
    MSD = "Europe/Moscow";
    MSK = "Europe/Moscow";
    MST = "America/Denver";
    NZDT = "Pacific/Auckland";
    NZST = "Pacific/Auckland";
    PDT = "America/Los_Angeles";
    PET = "America/Lima";
    PHT = "Asia/Manila";
    PKT = "Asia/Karachi";
    PST = "America/Los_Angeles";
    SGT = "Asia/Singapore";
    UTC = UTC;
    WAT = "Africa/Lagos";
    WEST = "Europe/Lisbon";
    WET = "Europe/Lisbon";
    WIT = "Asia/Jakarta";
}
```

Hope this will be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

```
public let Date_format_Default:String = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
```

Set this format string for UTC string;

```
public let Date_format_Z:String = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ"
public let Time_zone_UTC:String = "UTC"

open class func convertDate2UTC(_ date:String)->(String){
    var df_:DateFormatter?=DateFormatter()
    df_!.dateFormat=Date_format_Z
    let tz_=TimeZone(identifier: Time_zone_UTC)
    df_!.timeZone=tz_
    let df_s=df_!.date(from: date)

    df_!.dateFormat=Date_format_Default
    let string_=df_!.string(from: df_s!)

    df_ = nil
    return string_;
}
```

Comment: 1) The OP does not have a date string so what is the point of this code? 2) Why explicitly set the variable types when most of them can be determined implicitly? 3) Why did you make `df_` an optional? There's no reason for that and it results in your code being polluted with needless `!`.